# What are my options for laying concrete block around lolly columns?

Tags: masonry

I have a project where a concrete wall has been poured with lolly columns embedded in it. I want to lay concrete block from the poured wall to the sill. What are my options for laying the concrete block around the columns?

Comment: Pictures, please? Is this a short wall with columns sticking out the top that you wan to build upwards?

Comment: [Lolly?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lollipop) [Lally!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lally_column) - lol.